# How to Disable or hide SharePoint "Open with Explorer" menu option in document library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, powershell, ribbon

I want to Disable or hide SharePoint "Open with Explorer" menu option in document library without switching off the checkboxes "Use Remote Interfaces"
"Use Client Integration Features (removes Edit in … option)" in my custom permission level.Any PowerShell or Object Model way achieving this? TIA

Answer (score 3):

Following are the steps to remove this button from Ribbon

Create an empty SharePoint 2010 Solution, you may give your favorite name to it
Add a feature by right clicking on the Features in Solution Explorer
Right click on the Project and add a new item, choose empty element and name it
Open the Elements.xml file from the newly added item
Copy & paste the following XML into the Elements.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
       <CustomAction
         Id="RemoveRibbonButton"
         Location="CommandUI.Ribbon">
              <CommandUIExtension>
                     <CommandUIDefinitions>
                           <CommandUIDefinition
                             Location="Ribbon.Library.Actions.OpenWithExplorer" />
                     </CommandUIDefinitions>
              </CommandUIExtension>
       </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

Deploy the Solution and observe that “Open with Explorer” button will be removed from the Ribbon.